# Why is drop down menu show extra padding/margin with hover?

Tags: html, css

Why is drop down menu show extra padding/margin with hover (MOBILE)? Please use your expertise to solve it.

Where is the mistake please? I cannot fix it.

https://jsfiddle.net/4bnxuqyj/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Drop Down menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Cascade.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>The Drop Down menu</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Mobile</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">iPhone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Samsung</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Laptop</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: darkred;
    color: beige;
}

header h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 120px;
    height: 40px;

}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-table;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

nav ul li a{
    color: antiquewhite;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: cornflowerblue; 

}

/* Drop Down part below */

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hover the **Mobile** link the `<ul>` in that appears. The `<li>` that has the **Mobile** link gets the width of the `<ul>`.

To fix that you need to set a specific width for the top level menu items, for example:

```
nav > ul > li {
    width:100px; // Change to any value fitting your needs
}
```

The use of the `>` operator ensures that this rule will apply only to the top level `<li>` items.

**Note**: Your menu needs some additional work, but this spcific issue is resolved by setting a fixed width.

Comment: Here is your fiddle with my CSS added https://jsfiddle.net/4bnxuqyj/1/. As you can see, on hover the **Mobile** link does not change its width.

Comment: Why samsung is not getting background ? + browser change its width width

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, your implementation has some additional issues. If you are not interested in making a menu on your own I would suggest using a plugin. One good implementation is the [superfish plugin](https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish).